# How to install CH340G in iOS

Tags: arduino-uno

I have bought a new Arduino UNO and it works on CH340G. I want to code it using iOS phone, don't have a PC is there any way to install CH340G driver for iOS.

Comment: your question is about the IOS, not about the arduino ... do a search for IOS ch430g driver ... if you find it, install it, otherwise you are out of luck .... do you even have a USB port on your phone?

Comment: You *may* have better luck searching for "CH340G" rather than "CH430G" as you'd had it in your original revision.  I wouldn't expect much though.